# Timeout when Connecting to MongoDB Atlas from Azure App Service

Tags: c#, mongodb, azure

I'm trying to connect to my MongoDB database using the following setup:

```
public ReplybotServiceLayer(MongoDbSettings databaseSettings)
{
    var connectionString = $"mongodb+srv://{databaseSettings.User}:{databaseSettings.Password}@{databaseSettings.Cluster}.mongodb.net/{DatabaseName}?w=majority&connect=replicaSet";
    var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
    var database = client.GetDatabase(DatabaseName);
    _guildResponsesCollection = database.GetCollection<GuildResponseEntity>("responses");
    _guildConfigurationsCollection = database.GetCollection<GuildConfigurationEntity>("configuration");
}

public async Task<IList<TriggerResponse>?> GetResponsesForGuild(ulong guildId)
{
    var filter = Builders<GuildResponseEntity>.Filter.Eq("guildId", guildId.ToString());
    var guildResponses = await _guildResponsesCollection.Find(filter).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    var triggerResponses = guildResponses?.Responses;
    return triggerResponses?.Select(tr => tr.ToDomain()).ToList();
}
```

This connection works when running my app locally, but when I publish my app to Azure, the endpoint times out after about 30 seconds with the following error:

> "A timeout occurred after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 }, OperationsCountServerSelector }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode : "ReplicaSet", Type : "ReplicaSet", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [] }."

I even tried temporarily enabling "access from anywhere" in MongoDB Atlas, and it didn't work, so it shouldn't be a network access issue in theory.

What could be causing this time out? Is there any way for me to check for more details?

Comment: driver doesn't see any servers for some reason. Try enabling SDAM events and see what it will show you https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.17/reference/driver_core/sdamevents/

Comment: looks like that method is obsolete actually, says to use a LoggerFactory instead but I can't find anything on that

Comment: yes, both ways will work. I didn't use loggerFactory though

Comment: yeah  I can't really find any documentation on how to use that so I'm a bit stuck here still.

Comment: you should analyze what happens with your servers (search for their endpoints). In particular whether they're presented in ServerDescriptionChangedEvent and ClusterDescriptionChangedEvent

Comment: Also pay attention on HeartbeatException field

Comment: where am I looking for this information?

Comment: `HeartbeatException` is part of ServerDescriptionChangedEvent

Comment: yes but where do I look for those events?

Comment: see link above. One option is in this file `clientSetting.SdamLogFilename = @"c:\sdam.log"`

Comment: Right, so my confusion in all of this stems from: it doesn't want me to use that property, so I can't find how to use the LoggerFactory method, AND I don't know where on Azure to retrieve that file from once it's created.

Comment: see https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/csharp/current/fundamentals/logging/

Comment: Alright I set that up with a console logger, can I see those logs in the Azure portal now?

Comment: The driver logger implementation uses a default logger machinery based on ILogger: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.ilogger?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0. So it should be possible to do it somehow. See also here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/logging?tabs=command-line. But I don't have particular code to provide as example. ` in the Azure portal now` - have you tried?

Comment: Are they on the same vnet? What networking configuration do you have on the DB? IP filtering? Have you tried using the connection string provided by cosmos verbatim rather than doing an interpolated string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I ended up coming to was rather silly - the secrets had not properly saved in the configuration on Azure so it was legitimately unauthorized. I think there's helpful suggestions in the answers and comments here otherwise if you're running into a similar problem and happening upon this post.

Answer (score 1):

Writing it as answer since it's quite big.

Your issue is that for some reason, driver doesn't see any server (you can see it in this part of error message `..Servers : []..`). It's impossible to know what is wrong in your particular case without getting more details from events (Most likely something wrong in server or dns configuration). The best way is to look at `ClusterRemovingServerEvent` [event](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.18/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_Core_Events_ClusterRemovingServerEvent.htm) which contains a removing Reason field. But as I mentioned above, something can be visible from `ServerDescriptionChangedEvent` [event](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.18/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_Core_Events_ServerDescriptionChangedEvent.htm) and `ClusterDescriptionEventChanged` [event](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.18/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_Core_Events_ClusterDescriptionChangedEvent.htm) too.

There are a number of ways to get such details:

1. SdamLogFilename:

   ```
   clientSetting.SdamLogFilename = @"c:\sdam.log"
   ```
2. Create a custom event subscriber. See [here](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.18/reference/driver_core/events/). There, you will have full control over what events to subscribe on and how gather and print them.

The above ways are obsoleted, but still work.

3. .NET Logging. The most modern way. See [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/csharp/current/fundamentals/logging/). It's done with [ILogger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.ilogger?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) interface and can use any logger that supports such interface. In the above example from mongo docs, the used logger is console, but you can use any other including custom implementation (see above microsoft link).